# Base localization not loaded keeps on last used one

Tags: ios, localization, interface-builder, localizable.strings

I'm localizing my app to support English and Spanish.
If I set the device to Spanish and then I change to a non supported language, for example Italian or French, the app still shows the labels in Spanish. I'm not setting the values from code using NSLocalizedString. I'm localizing it in Interface Builder using the Main.strings file.

I have the Base localization in English, so it should show the content in English for other languages, but it’s not working. It keeps showing the last localization used.
Is this the correct behavior? How can I force it to use the Base localization when the language is neither English or Spanish?